# Darker Buttons in ListView Item

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

i've got a Activity with a ListView. I wrote an extra xml-file for the ListView-Item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutPalettenItem"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    tools:context=".PalettenAdapter" >
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPalettenBez"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Bezeichnung"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenMinus"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see the xml includes two Buttons (+ and -). Everything works fine and the item loads in the list. Also the Buttons are clickable **but** their color is darker. I set the background to `@android:drawable/btn_default_holo_light`. They look fine in layout but the Buttons stay darker, when i launch the app.
[image: Screenshot of my app]

Let me know if you need more code on this.
I would be very glad if you could help me solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The default button background color of **Theme.MaterialComponents** is defined in your themes.xml file with the attribute **colorPrimary** eg: `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/gray</item>` but changing this color will affect all your widgets.

You can use **`app:backgroundTint`** attribute to change the button background color like below:

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
```

You have to add also the **xmlns:app** namespace on your root xml View like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Result with the above colour @android:color/holo_blue_dark using **Theme.MaterialComponents** will be like below:

[image: button_color]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
If i paste in `app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"` in the xml of my button it says "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix". If i change it into 
`android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"` it leads to an error "error: no resource identifier found for attribute 'backgroundTint' in package 'android'"

Comment: Check my updated answer how to add the xmlns:app namespace on your Root View.

Comment: Hey, i just tried it again with your updated answer but it did not have any effect

Comment: Most probably its because you are not inherit from parent=Theme.MaterialComponents theme in your themes.xml file and you inherit from eg: parent=Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. The above answer works only for Theme.MaterialComponents theme. If you are not inheriting from MaterialComponents then by adding just the android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" into the button should be work.